# Finding the roots of a quartic

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I try to find the roots of $f(x)=x^4+(4a-2)x^3+(6a^2-6a)x^2+(4a^3-7a^2)x+ a^4-2a^3
=0$ with $0<a<1$.

**How do i get with Mathematica all solutions (general expressions, real and complex)?**

With

```
Solve[x^4 + (a+b+c+d-2)x^3 +(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-2b-2c-a-d) x^2 + (abc+abd+acd+bcd-ab-ac-ad-bd-cd-a-d+b+c)x +abcd-abc-bcd-ad+bc== 0, x,Quartics->True] // Last
```

i just get $x$ in radicals.

In a other question someone writed that he tried

```
sol = Solve[f(x)==0,x];x1=x/.sol[[1]];x2=x/.sol[[2];x3=x/.sol[[3];x4=x/.sol[[4];
```

but with this I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment on the code you provided: when you write `abc` Mathematica reads it as a single variable/parameter. If you want multiplication you should have done `a b c` or equivalently `a*b*c`.

In the OP you wrote

$$f(x)=x^4+(4a-2)x^3+(6a^2-6a)x^2+(4a^3-7a^2)x+ a^4-2a^3 = 0$$

with $0<a<1$.

If you code that

```
f[x_] := x^4 + (4 a - 2) x^3 + (6 a^2 - 6 a) x^2 + (4 a^3 - 7 a^2) x + a^4 - 2 a^3

sltn = Assuming[0 < a < 1, Solve[f[x] == 0, x]]
```

you get

> [image: roots]

Finally, if you use the `Last` command you get only the last solution that Mathematica provided.

**Edit: addressing the comment by the author of the OP**

Mathematica provided us with four solutions. We can quickly check if they are all the same -they are not. The following compares the first and second solution and gives a non-trivial output. Hence, we don't see the same solution four times.

```
(Values@sltn[[1]])/(Values@sltn[[2]]) // Factor // Simplify
```

With regards to what their explicit value is. Well, the first one is `x` equals to `sltn[[1]]` and likewise for the rest. The expressions are explicit in the sense that Mathematica solved `x` in terms of `a` which is the constrained parameter. Not sure, what you meant by explicit.

Checking reality of the solutions.

One straightforward way of doing this is to create tables of explicit values for the solutions 1 to 4.

```
Table[Values@sltn[[1]], {a, 10^-10, 1, 1/10}] // N // Chop
```

> [image: one]

Likewise the second one gives complex numbers.

```
Table[Values@sltn[[3]], {a, 10^-10, 1, 1/10}] // N // Chop
```

> [image: three]

and likewise the forth gives real numbers.

**Edit 2: on ``V13.0.0**

The output is

> [image: v1300]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But why is the same solution shown four times in the output? Should we conclude that there are four different solutions? And what do they look like explicitly?  Which are complex and real?

Comment: If i code like you:
f[x_] := x^4 + (4 a - 2) x^3 + (6 a^2 - 6 a) x^2 + (4 a^3 - 7 a^2) x + a^4 - 2 a^3
sltn = Assuming[0 < a < 1, Solve[f[x] == 0, x]]

i get: {{x->i Root[-2a^3+...+#1^4 &, 1] + Root[...]}, {x->...}, {...}, {{x->i Root[... &, 3] + Root[... &,1]}}. What does this mean?

Comment: @toni_iva for the first comment you left, please see the edits to my answer. For the second one, try to run my command with a clean kernel. It should give you the output I showed you. I am sitting on `V12.0.0`. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using online V.13.0.0, but i don’t get the output in your comment. :(

Comment: @toni_iva well you do get it, right? You get the roots and under the root you get what I am presenting. Can you try to follow the next steps? I have to go now, but I will check later with `V13.0.0` and post an update

Comment: I am still confused by the following things: 

1.: The four solutions, which you get as output, look nevertheless the same (even if you have shown that it is not so, all numbers are the same). 

2nd: I get a completely different output. 

3rd: To check whether the solutions are real or complex, you simply inserted values (10^{-10},1,1/10). But why do so many output values come out? To what do they belong? By the way, I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @toni_iva I added a screenshot from `V13.0.0` to show you the output. As you see, when I pick one of the solutions and give a numerical value to `a` I get an answer. So, it seems that all is well. More comments: you said that the numerical coefficients of the solutions look the same. True, but they are combined differently and that makes them distinct solutions as far as I can tell. Also, in the statement of the problem `a` is a parameter between 0 and 1. So, I created a table with a bunch of values. Each value of `a` leads to a different numerical solution for `x` and that's why you get many.

Comment: @toni_iva in the last print screen you can see that when I choose one solution and one value for `a` I get back precisely one expression. I think you missed that I had the `Table` command previously. And you are welcome :-)